# Ultimate Members Default Post Layout problem

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization

Hey Developer & Coding Expert
I Am Using A Child Theme In My Wordpress Site . And Also Using Ultimate Member Plugin For User Profile . When Any One Click On Users Profile He Will See All Post Of This User . And This Post Layout Is Ultimate Members Default Post Layout. Now I Wanna Change This Layout To My Themes Default Post Layout In The Ultimate Members Post Tab ?
[wanna layout (my theme default layout)](https://prnt.sc/vfhg3q)

[UM layout](http://prnt.sc/vfhggo)

Comment: I'd guess the layout comes from one of your theme's templates not Ultimate Member. (And I'd guess the whole page is just your theme's author page too, not generated by Ultimate Member.) Is this the same layout as your regular archive pages?

Comment: Thanks my regular archive pages layout is like 1st screenshot . (https://prnt.sc/vfhg3q) you can see